# Fullpage.js content jumping to section when first loading

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

having an issue with fullpage.js jumping to different sections/slide as page loads. 
Scenario:

Currently have 7 sections/slides that have quite a bit in them. 
each slide has an anchor so the sections read mysite.com/anchor

the ISSUE:
say you are on mysite.com/anchor3 and you refresh, as the site is loading and you navigate to a different slide, once all the content is loaded the site jumps back to mysite.com/anchor3

am not sure what else to do and have tried the following:
**have initialized the script on document ready not load.** 
and have set css:

and have done this as well.

```
html,
body,
#fullpage,
.section{
    height: 100%;
}
```

any ideas are appreciated. 
here is video showing issue. 
https://dha4w82d62smt.cloudfront.net/items/2P2k3K2V3f0S002R2U1w/Screen%20Recording%202018-09-07%20at%2001.17%20PM.mov?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2925693

I suspect it has something to do with the anchors so am wondering aside from removing them if there is a way to disable them.

here is js

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        navigation:false,
        autoScrolling:false,
        menu:"#my-nav",
        anchors: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'],
        licenseKey: ('15560068-077B4EC4-B9C3AECE-631A2B58'),
        verticalCentered: true,
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
            activateNavItem($('#my-nav').find('li').eq(nextIndex - 1));
        },
        afterRender: function() {
            activateNavItem($('#my-nav').find('li').eq($('.section.active').index()))
        }
    });

    $('.bell').click(function() {
        if ($("#socialmediaoverlay").hasClass("socialoverlay") && $(this).attr("id") != "socialmedialink") {
            $("#socialmediaoverlay").fadeToggle();
            $("#socialmediaoverlay").toggleClass("socialoverlay");

            $("#fullpage").toggleClass("blurred");
        }
        var destination = $(this).closest('li');
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(destination.index() + 1);
    });

    function activateNavItem(item) {
        item.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    };
```

Comment: I would say that quite a bit more information is needed like a full context working example to avoid wild speculation ;)

Comment: here is a video with the issue, you can see on the navigation bar that am on an item below, when I hit refresh and click on the top button, it then jumps back donw to the initial slide

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use lazy load for elements that take a long time to load causing the issue.

Any media element or image can be lazy loaded.

Just use `data-src` instead of `src`. That should make your site load faster and scroll to the section faster.

Comment: thanks yeah I got that in there too. It's not mainly that it's slow, the jumping to first slide if you refresh on a different section

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you said. What do you mean?

Comment: if I am in another section down the page and refresh, it snaps back to the top of the page.